# blender doesnt import textures from obj

Tags: textures, blender, texture-mapping

I have this obj starting with:

mtllib HogwartsOBJ.mtl

and the mtl has all the textures like this:

```
newmtl c69dd250_dds
    Ns 10.0000
    Ni 1.5000
    d 1.0000
    Tr 0.0000
    Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
    illum 2
    Ka 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    Kd 0.7000 0.7000 0.7000
    Ks 0.1000 0.1000 0.1000
    Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    map_Ka /texturasbmp/c69dd250.bmp
    map_Kd /texturasbmp/c69dd250.bmp
```

and those textures are there
C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\harry\Otros Assets\Hogwarts3D\Hogwarts3D\texturasbmp
and the obj is in C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\harry\Otros Assets\Hogwarts3D\Hogwarts3D\

but blender doesn't import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put render mode instead of solid